# Windows Hooks to intercept the mouse click?

Tags: java, operating-system

**Windows Hooks to intercept the mouse click?**
I do not know that how to use hook
more over please provide the exact hook to intercept the mouse click
One thing ,I want to use in java application
So

> please provide me a proper  guide to use also

Thank you

Comment: what are you using? C# or Java?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on why you want to do this ? If you are using Swing a GlassPane might be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response to the op. But I hope this could help the others.

The following library leverages the Windows Hook mechanism to achieve a global keyboard/mouse listener. And mimic the AWT event programming experience.

http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JNI. Here are two examples who it helps you.

1. [Java Global Keyboard Hook](http://www.jinvoke.com/demos/MouseHook/src)
2. [MouseHook.java](http://www.jinvoke.com/demos/MouseHook/src)

Comment: JNA might be easier to implement.